# How can I call an ASP.NET web service when new data is inserted in a SQL Server table?

Tags: asp.net, sql-server

How can I call an ASP.NET web service when new data is inserted in a SQL Server database table?

Answer (score 2):

You can add an assembly to your Db and fire the code in a trigger, on insert.

Comment: without using trigger, can be possible.

Comment: You can fire it in the script doing the insert.